# Logback.xml is not generating the logs separately for error and debug in separate rollingfile

Tags: logback, spring-logback

I want to generate logs in separate file for different level like error or debug. Means when root level is enable for Debug the logs should be generated in debug file only. And when root level is enable for error the logs should be generated in error file. But for my logback.xml configuration the logs are generating in both the files as the same time.
Please help.

=========Below is the logback.xml========

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="logs" />

        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>
                    %-5level | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%thread]  %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </layout>
            <!-- filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>FATAL</level>
                <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>ERROR</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>WARN</level>
                <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter-->
        </appender>
        <appender name="Recipe_DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${DEV_HOME}/Recipe_DEBUG.log</file>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.ThresholdFilter">      
                <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>


            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %-5level | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%thread]  %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- rollover daily -->
                <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/Recipe_DEBUG.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>
        <appender name="Recipe_ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/Recipe_ERROR.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.ThresholdFilter">      
                <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %-5level | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%thread]  %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/Recipe_ERROR.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="Recipe_ERROR" level="ERROR" additivity="true"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Recipe_DEBUG" level="DEBUG" additivity="true"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There were some issues in filter and root tag, correcting and attaching the corrected file.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="logs" />

        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>
                    %-5level | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%thread]  %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </layout>
            <!-- filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>FATAL</level>
                <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>ERROR</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>WARN</level>
                <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
            </filter-->
        </appender>
        <appender name="Recipe_DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${DEV_HOME}/Recipe_DEBUG.log</file>
            <append>true</append>
            <!--filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">      
                <level>DEBUG</level>
            </filter-->
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>

            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %-5level | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%thread]  %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- rollover daily -->
                <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/Recipe_DEBUG.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>
        <appender name="Recipe_ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/Recipe_ERROR.log</file>
        <!--filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter-->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %-5level | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%thread]  %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/Recipe_ERROR.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!--additivity=false ensures this log data only goes to the this log, and no one more -->
    <logger name="root" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Recipe_ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="Recipe_DEBUG"/>
    </logger>


</configuration>
```